# R Script to rearrange the elements of a vector by interleaving it

Tags: r

How to write an R-script to initialize a vector with integers, rearrange the elements by interleaving the
first half elements with the second half elements and store in the same vector without using pre-defined function and display the updated vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or using `mapply`:

```r
vec <- 1:20

c(mapply(\(x,y) c(x,y), vec[1:10], vec[11:20]))

#>  [1]  1 11  2 12  3 13  4 14  5 15  6 16  7 17  8 18  9 19 10 20
```

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a homework question, and it would be nice to see some effort on your own part, but it's pretty straightforward to do this in R.

Suppose your vector looks like this:

```r
vec <- 1:20

vec
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Then you can just do:

```r
c(t(cbind(vec[1:10], vec[11:20])))
#>  [1]  1 11  2 12  3 13  4 14  5 15  6 16  7 17  8 18  9 19 10 20
```

This works by joining the two vectors into a 10 x 2 matrix, then transposing that matrix and turning it into a vector.

Answer (score 1):

We may use `matrix` directly and `c`oncatenate

```
c(matrix(vec, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE))
```

-output

```
[1]  1 11  2 12  3 13  4 14  5 15  6 16  7 17  8 18  9 19 10 20
```

#### data

```
vec <- 1:20
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try this using `order` + `%%`

```
> vec[order((seq_along(vec) - 1) %% (length(vec) / 2))]
 [1]  1 11  2 12  3 13  4 14  5 15  6 16  7 17  8 18  9 19 10 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `rbind` on the 2 halves of the vector, which creates a matrix with two rows. Then, we can then turn the matrix into a vector, which will go through column by column (i.e., 1, 11, 2, 12...). However, this will only work for even vectors.

```
vec <- 1:20

c(rbind(vec[1:10], vec[11:20]))

# [1]  1 11  2 12  3 13  4 14  5 15  6 16  7 17  8 18  9 19 10 20
```

So, for uneven vectors, we can use `order`, which will return the indices of the numbers in the two `seq_along` vectors.

```
vec2 <- 1:21

order(c(seq_along(vec2[1:10]),seq_along(vec2[11:21])))

# [1]  1 11  2 12  3 13  4 14  5 15  6 16  7 17  8 18  9 19 10 20 21
```